# MySQL - show query by query id in mysql < 5.1.7

Tags: mysql

I have a long running transaction running on a database

```
---TRANSACTION 2 4166167596, ACTIVE 14868 sec, process no 7906, OS thread id 1169635648
MySQL thread id 34318076, query id 1997556522 10.186.131.136 admin
```

The above is an output from `SHOW INNODB ENGINE STATUS` command

I want to see what query is running by with the query id 1997556522. `SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST` is not an option, since it requires me to manually find the query from a list of hundreds.

This [SO Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/929612/how-to-customize-show-processlist-in-mysql) says you can do that by querying the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PROCESSLIST` table on MySQL 5.1.7 and greater. Is it possible to do so on an older version?

I am running on MySQL 5.0.45

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should use the thread id, not the query id.

If you have shell access you can execute `show full processlist` and then grep for the relevant thread id.

For example:

```
mysql -e "show full processlist;" | grep 34318076
```